# Django REST: Nested object add on create (POST) not just update (PUT)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using [Django rest](http://django-rest-framework.org/)

Below is how I had my serializer.py.

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'active', 'type')
```

**Type is a flatview**

I then changed  it so 'type' was nested for each profile like this...

```
class TypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Type
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'active')

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    type = TypeSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'active', 'type'')
```

now this works perfect, but I can now only update 'type' when in profile detail it's now read-only.

How can I add type when creating a new profile and still keep this nested view?

I hope I have explained this clearly .

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I just read this:

> Note: Nested serializers are only suitable for read-only
>   representations, as there are cases where they would have ambiguous or
>   non-obvious behavior if used when updating instances. For read-write
>   representations you should always use a flat representation, by using
>   one of the RelatedField subclasses.

So that makes sense. So I changed it to....

```
type = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
```

That puts it back in the POST and work, but it's a shame, can I not represent 'type' with ID and the name so it makes more sense to the end user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Full support of writable nested serializers is a [work in progress](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/395), but in the mean time one solution is to override the `create` method in the view in each case:

```
class FooListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Foo
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data=request.DATA

        f = Foo.objects.create()

        # ... create nested objects from request data ...  

        # ...
        return Response(serializer.data, 
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)
```

Probably not ideal, but it works for me until the proper way comes along.

Comment: I found that SlugRelatedField allow me to now change from the id to something meaningful like title or name of the field but thats using a flatfield not nested. I'll retry with nested and see if the override could work.

Comment: Can you explain, how can we validate other fields here ?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in django-rest-framework, and I have created a View for doing this real quick, you can find it in this gist: https://gist.github.com/edulix/5311365

Basic usage of **CRUDManyToManyView** is the following:

**views.py**

```
from models import Project
from serializers import TaskSerializer
from lib.crudmanytomanyview import CRUDManyToManyView

class ProjectTasks(CRUDManyToManyView):
    model = Project
    field_name = 'tasks'
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
'',
    url(r'^projects/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/tasks/((?P<field_pk>[0-9]+)/)?$',
        views.ProjectTasks.as_view()),
)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Task

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=False, null=False)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=False, null=False)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task, related_name='projects')
```

Then you can do things like:

- **GET projects/12/tasks/** will list the project tasks
- **POST projects/12/tasks/1/** which will add the task 1 to the list of project 12 tasks (task 1 must already exist)
- **DELETE projects/12/tasks/1/** which will remove the task 1 from the list of project 12 tasks

Answer (score 5):

This is now supported (I am using version 2.3.6 but it might be introduced earlier). You can use it in the serializer direcly like this:

```
class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Song

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    songs = SongSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Is this code snippet correct? Where did ImageFeatureSerializer come from?  And SongSerializer's model is another SongSerializer?

Comment: Sorry, I was converting some of my own code to fit the above example, and was in a bit of a rush. This should work. Thanks!

Comment: @RaresMusina What would a POST request look like now?

Comment: @EvanZamir Unfortunately I haven't touched this in over 3 years, so I'm not really sure how the framework evolved. Sorry

Comment: @RaresMusina Don't worry I figured out my problems!