# Posting a one-to-many relationship

Tags: django, one-to-many, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to expose an API to my Django model through Django REST framework.

I have an object `Observation`. An observation can contain multiple things that have been observed. So I represented it like this:

```
class Observation(models.Model):

    photo_file = models.ImageField( upload_to=img_dir,   blank=True, null=True )
    titestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()


class ObservedThing(models.Model):
    thing = models.ForeignKey(Thing) # the thing being observed
    observation = models.ForeignKey(Observation, related_name='observed_thing')
    value = models.FloatField()
```

As I understand this is a one-to-many relationship.

I now have an API View:

```
class ObsvList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint that represents a list of observations.
    """
    model = Observation
    serializer_class = ObsvSerializer
```

and the corresponding serialiser:

```
class ObsvSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    observed_thing = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Observation
```

What do I have to do to be able to POST an observation with several things detected? I cannot figure it out. Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(answer more or less copied from another [similar but less clear question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978464/django-rest-nested-object-add-on-create-post-not-just-update-put))

To create multiple related objects in a single POST requires *writable nested serializers* which are not yet available.

Full support is a [work in progress](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/395), but in the mean time one (hacky) solution is to override the `create` method in the view in each case:

```
class FooListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Foo
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data=request.DATA

        f = Foo.objects.create()

        # ... create nested objects from request data ...  

        # ...
        return Response(serializer.data, 
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)
```

Probably not ideal, but it works for me until the proper way comes along.

The other option is to create the related `Observation` objects individually with separate POSTs, and the use [PrimaryKeyRelatedField or HyperlinkedRelatedField](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html) to make the associations in the final `ObservedThing` POST.

Answer (score 7):

I know this thread has already an answer but I started working to solve this problem, and since this post was one of my inspirations, I would like to share my final solution. It can be useful to someone. I have the models, so the parent class:

```
#parent model class
class Parent(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'parent'
```

then, the child class:

```
#child model class
class Child(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'child'
```

I had to define the serializers, since I didn't want to create a router accessible url to directly manage Children objects, but I wanted to create them through the ModelViewSet of the parent ModelViewSet, this is what I needed:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Banner
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class ParentSerializerNested(ParentSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer(many=True)
```

I was then ready to create the ModelViewSet, overriding/extending the create/update mixins, and make it generic in order to reuse it for other cases:

```
class ParentChildViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_parent(data=request.DATA,
                                            files=request.FILES)

        try:
            if serializer.is_valid():
                with transaction.commit_on_success():
                    self.pre_save(serializer.object)
                    parent = serializer.save(force_insert=True)
                    self.post_save(parent, created=True)

                    # need to insert children records
                    for child in request.DATA[self.child_field]:
                        child[self.parent_field] = parent.id
                        child_record = self.serializer_child(data=child)
                        if child_record.is_valid():
                            child_record.save(force_insert=True)
                        else:
                            raise ValidationError('Child validation failed')

                    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

                    serializer.data[self.child_field] = self.serializer_child(
                        self.model_child.objects.filter(
                            **{self.parent_field: parent.id}).all(),
                            many=True).data
                    return Response(serializer.data,
                                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                                    headers=headers)
        except ValidationError:
            pass
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So I can reuse it for every nested relationship case I have in my app like this:

```
class ParentViewSet(ParentChildViewSet):
    child_field = 'children'
    parent_field = 'parent'
    model = Parent
    model_child = Child
    serializer_class = ParentSerializerNested
    serializer_parent = ParentSerializer
    serializer_child = ChildSerializer
```

And in the end, the routing:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'parents', ParentViewSet)
```

It works like a charm!

Comment: Thaks for the answer, but you are using a `ModelViewSet ` here , I think it would have been more cooler when you used a `genericView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
thing = models.ManyToManyField('Thing')
```

you need to use many to many relationship for creating a temporary table that will store the keys and associate data automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but my intermediate table is the ``ObservedThing`` one. The ``ManyToManyField`` only works if you don't have any other info attached to the relationship. What I can do is to have ``thing = models.ManyToManyField(Thing, through='ObservedThing')``, but that still doesn't solve my original problem.